# Video streaming through web service and rendering - Any Issues?

Tags: web-services, video

We have a web service that sends the video content in the response as binary (in different formats asx, asf, ram, mpeg, mpg, mpe, qt, mov, avi, movie, wmv, smil, mp4, mxf, gxf, flv, 3gp, f4v, mj2, omf, dv, vob).

Do you see any issue with performance, if I have an intermediate application which makes a request to web service to retrieve video content and render in browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as the web service returns binary data directly, then there will be no performance hit.  If this is an XML or SOAP web service that wraps the whole thing in a SOAP envelope and bae64 encodes it to make it all text, then you will not be able to play it directly and it will have a big impact on bandwidth, cpu, and memory.

Also note that by serving the video directly instead of using a true streaming protocol the user will only be able to seek within the portion downloaded so far.  A streaming protocol like RTSP, RTMP, or the many varieties of HTTP Streaming allow seeking to any part of the file and only downloading the part seeked to.

Comment: Thanks for providing valuable information. If you know, could you please share a link for any documentation or sample examples for similar kind of work where and how the video/digital content management systems expose the videos; and how the clients which consume these videos - and render in browser.